# how to upload a SharePoint site template (.wsp) when the solution link is missing in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010, site-template, site-settings

I am trying to transfer a SharePoint page to a different SharePoint site. I noticed that the links to do this are not visible in the `site settings menu`.

I figured out how to save the site as a template by adding

"`_layout/savetmpl.apsx`" to the end of the URL.

now I can't figure out how to upload the template file to the new SharePoint site because the solutions link is not under the Galleries section in site settings.

Would anyone happen to know a way I can upload the template to the site??

Answer (score 0):

The Solutions library is in the root site of the site collection, so you will have to go to the Site Settings of the *root site* in order to see the Solutions link.

Comment: yes I am in the root site but the solutions link is not there

Answer (score 0):

Use the farm account or Site Collection administrator User to do that :

- Go to site settings of your current site.
- Go to top level site settings.

[image]

- below Web Designer Galleries > Check `Solutions`.

[image]

Comment: I don't have the site collection adminstration section and the only link in the galleries section is "list templates"

Comment: are you have  as asite collection administrator  permission

Comment: This is because you don't have sufficient permission as full control or your user  not a site collection administrator.

Comment: I am the site admin. unless the company I work for blocked this feature from us. but I was able to make a site into a template.